# Produce nested xml from table; what method is best Path, Element?

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2019

I need to produce XML out of my table in the format like below. Can you advise what method I should go with (Path, Element, Raw) or could it be a combination of several?

Please find below my test data and some code I just started. Also see the requested XML format with a lot of nests. Can this be done in a single `SELECT` or can I compose various parts by level?

```sql
SELECT *  INTO #t FROM (
SELECT  2020 yy, 'Alpha' CompanyName, 
   'BossA'  FirstName_Owner, 'Smith'  LastName_Owner,  'John1' FirstName_Client , 'Dow1'  LasttName_Client,'Yes'  Active union
SELECT  2020 yy, 'Alpha' CompanyName, 
   'BossA'  FirstName_Owner, 'Smith'  LastName_Owner,  'Peter2' FirstName_Client  , 'Redd2'  LasttName_Client,'No'   Active UNION
SELECT  2020 yy, 'Alpha' CompanyName, 
 'BossyBB' FirstName_Owner, 'Green'  LastName_Owner, 'Mary' FirstName_Client ,  'Robbins3'  LasttName_Client,'Yes'  Active
)a  ---   SELECT TOP 100 * FROM #t           --    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS  #t


SELECT    yy,   CompanyName  
  --SELECT 
  -- FirstName_Owner,   LastName_Owner,   
  -- FirstName_Client , LasttName_Client,  Active  
FROM #t
FOR XML RAW('CompanyInfo') , ELEMENTS -- Path
--FOR XML RAW('Client'), ROOT ('Clients')
```

Requested output in XML format for my test data:

```
<GemReport> 
    <Version>2.0</Version> 
    <Company>  
        <CompanyInfo> 
                     <Year>2020</Year> 
                     <CompanyName>Alpha</CompanyName> 
            <Owners> 
                <Owner> 
                        <FirstName>John</FirstName> 
                        <LastName>Doe</LastName> 
                    <Clients> 
                        <Client> 
                             <FirstName>John1</FirstName> 
                             <LastName>Doe1</LastName> 
                             <Contract> 
                                <Active>Yes</Active> 
                             </Contract> 
                        </Client> 
                        <Client> 
                             <FirstName>Peter2</FirstName> 
                             <LastName>Redd2</LastName> 
                             <Contract> 
                                <Active>NO</Active> 
                             </Contract> 
                        </Client> 
                    </Clients> 
                </Owner> 
                <Owner> 
                        <FirstName>BossyBB</FirstName> 
                        <LastName>Green</LastName> 
                    <Clients> 
                        <Client> 
                             <FirstName>Mary</FirstName> 
                             <LastName>Robbins3</LastName> 
                             <Contract> 
                                <Active>Yes</Active> 
                             </Contract> 
                        </Client>               
                </Owners> 
        </CompanyInfo> 
    </Company> 
</GemReport>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your design is denormalised, you're going to need to use some self `JOIN`s here using CTEs to the `DISTINCT` values of the company and company owner details. Then you can nest your `FOR XML PATH`s for each layer (`Owners`, and `Clients`) with subqueries.

Most likely getting a performant solution, with a larger dataset, will actually be to fix your design and normalise it; then you don't need to scan the same table multiple times, and instead can have a table for the companies, owners, and clients, each with relevant primary/foreign key constraints and indexes.

```sql
USE Sandbox;
GO

SELECT *
INTO dbo.YourTable
FROM (SELECT 2020 AS yy,
             'Alpha' AS CompanyName,
             'BossA' AS FirstName_Owner,
             'Smith' AS LastName_Owner,
             'John1' AS FirstName_Client,
             'Dow1' AS LasttName_Client,
             'Yes' AS Active
      UNION --ALL? 
      SELECT 2020 AS yy,
             'Alpha' AS CompanyName,
             'BossA' AS FirstName_Owner,
             'Smith' AS LastName_Owner,
             'Peter2' AS FirstName_Client,
             'Redd2' AS LasttName_Client,
             'No' AS Active
      UNION --ALL? 
      SELECT 2020 AS yy,
             'Alpha' AS CompanyName,
             'BossyBB' AS FirstName_Owner,
             'Green' AS LastName_Owner,
             'Mary' AS FirstName_Client,
             'Robbins3' AS LasttName_Client,
             'Yes' AS Active) a;

GO
WITH Companies AS(
    SELECT DISTINCT
           CompanyName,
           yy
    FROM dbo.YourTable),
CompanyOwners AS(
    SELECT DISTINCT
           CompanyName,
           yy,
           FirstName_Owner,
           LastName_Owner
    FROM dbo.YourTable)
SELECT 2.0 AS Version,
       (SELECT C.yy AS [Year],
               C.CompanyName AS [CompanyName],
               (SELECT CO.FirstName_Owner AS FirstName,
                       CO.LastName_Owner AS LastName,
                       (SELECT YT.FirstName_Client AS FirstName,
                               YT.LasttName_Client AS LastName,
                               YT.Active AS [Contract/Active]
                        FROM dbo.YourTable YT
                        WHERE YT.yy = CO.yy
                          AND YT.CompanyName = CO.CompanyName
                          AND YT.FirstName_Owner = CO.FirstName_Owner --I hope this can't be NULL
                          AND YT.LastName_Owner = CO.LastName_Owner --I hope this can't be NULL
                        FOR XML PATH('Client'),ROOT('Clients'),TYPE)
                FROM CompanyOwners CO
                WHERE CO.yy = C.yy
                  AND CO.CompanyName = C.CompanyName
                FOR XML PATH('Owner'),ROOT('Owners'),TYPE)
        FROM Companies C
        FOR XML PATH('CompanyInfo'), ROOT('Company'),TYPE)
FOR XML PATH('GemReport')

GO
DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

Which produces the following XML:

```xml
<GemReport>
  <Version>2.0</Version>
  <Company>
    <CompanyInfo>
      <Year>2020</Year>
      <CompanyName>Alpha</CompanyName>
      <Owners>
        <Owner>
          <FirstName>BossA</FirstName>
          <LastName>Smith</LastName>
          <Clients>
            <Client>
              <FirstName>John1</FirstName>
              <LastName>Dow1</LastName>
              <Contract>
                <Active>Yes</Active>
              </Contract>
            </Client>
            <Client>
              <FirstName>Peter2</FirstName>
              <LastName>Redd2</LastName>
              <Contract>
                <Active>No</Active>
              </Contract>
            </Client>
          </Clients>
        </Owner>
        <Owner>
          <FirstName>BossyBB</FirstName>
          <LastName>Green</LastName>
          <Clients>
            <Client>
              <FirstName>Mary</FirstName>
              <LastName>Robbins3</LastName>
              <Contract>
                <Active>Yes</Active>
              </Contract>
            </Client>
          </Clients>
        </Owner>
      </Owners>
    </CompanyInfo>
  </Company>
</GemReport>
```

<sub>Note, this does not match the OP's required XML, as that is not valid XML. The last `Clients` and `Owner` nodes are *not* closed. I assumed this was in error.</sub>

Comment: Thanks much Thom !!! I can easily modify my input table as needed, for easy sample used demoralized  version.  I will check re closing Client and Owner nodes, my XML validator was OK.   I can see now all nested selects, and go with PATH

Comment: It's a shame there is no `XMLAGG` aggregate function. Your formatting could do with some help, it's quite cramped.

Comment: The formatting of what, @Charlieface, the XML? That's just how it came out of SSMS, I didn't care to put additional effort in.

Comment: I honestly don't see that as cramped at all, @Charlieface, everything is on a newline and indented appropriately.

Comment: Something like this perhaps https://dbfiddle.uk/Op_la9hn spaces after commas, and begin/end parens on newlines. Great answer anyway.

Comment: I find that *harder* to read, @Charlieface . I would call that cramped due to the lower amount of indentation to help identify parts of subqueries.